# Rails add array field to params.permit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, parameters

EDIT to reflect current answers and nested_attributes

I have the following models and controller

**reservation.rb**

```
  has_many :taxes, through: :tax_requests
  has_many :tax_requests, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :taxes
```

**reservation_controller.rb**

```
def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(
      :start_date, :end_date, :status, :tag_list, :sales_channel_id,
      :comments, :room_category_id, :client_id,
      tax_attributes: [:id, :name, :value, :abbreviation, :hotel_id])
end
```

**tax.rb**

```
  has_many :reservations, through: :tax_requests
  has_many :tax_requests

  validates :name, :value, :abbreviation, presence: true
```

**tax_request.rb**

```
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :tax
```

And in the reservation form view(for reservation creation)

```
= f.select :taxes, options_from_collection_for_select(Tax.all, :id, :abbreviation, @reservation.taxes), {}, multiple: true
```

But, when accesing `reservation_params`, I get all the params listed before, except for the :taxes param.
If I do `params[:reservation]` it does appear.

If I add taxes: [] to the permit, they do appear, but I get an error, that it is expecting a [Tax] when it actually is getting a [String]

Comment: You should read through the section on nested attributes: http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Here is the gist of how this works, I don't have your code in my system to test it however, but it should give you enough.

Taxes is going to be a collection so you probably need to accept nested attributes on the reservation object:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :taxes
```

And then modify the strong params method to understand that:

```
def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(
      :start_date, :end_date, :status, :tag_list, :sales_channel_id,
      :comments, :room_category_id, :client_id, tax_attributes: [:name, :value, :etc...]
end
```

A good read if you need clarification:
http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect this, but I can't get it to work yet.